# Refresh unbound text box when go to next record

Tags: ms-access

I have a bound form with couple unbound text box. How can I refresh or set up a default value when the whole form go to next record? Thanks! (VBA acceptable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add handler for Form_Current event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()    
Dim default_value As String

default_value = "0"    
Me.YourUnboundTextBox = default_value

End Sub
```